# How to properly install the mongodb java driver?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I want to create an application using MongoDB and java. But I can't find the right files or the right documentation as to explain how to install the MongoDB java driver.

A. I have:

1. Searched Google and couldn't find a proper answer
2. Taken a look at the [MongoDB documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/driver/getting-started/installation/) (But the documentation wasn't clear enough)

B. I have also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217129/installing-mongodb-java-driver) as to how you can install the MongoDB java driver but the answers there weren't clear.

So, is there any way (literally any way) to properly install the MongoDB java driver?

Comment: Are you using an IDE (like, Eclipse, etc.) or working from the command line to create your application? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, I am using maven @prasad_

Comment: Take a look at this: [MongoDB & Java CRUD Tutorial](https://developer.mongodb.com/quickstart/java-setup-crud-operations). The examples use Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no installation for the driver, you just have to add it to your dependencies in whatever tool you are using (maven, gradle, etc.) or add it to your classpath, you can find examples of how to add the dependecy for multiple tools [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.11.0-beta4)

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you explain as to what file should we add to our classpath

Comment: if you are not using maven or gradle and just a simple java project, you have to add this file https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.12.4/mongo-java-driver-3.12.4.jar to your classpath

Comment: I should add this file in the classpath meaning in the installation directory of the jdk, right?

Comment: no, you should not touch your jdk installation, you can put it in a lib directory on your project and use your IDE to set the class path for you or use the command line options -cp or --classpath for compiling/running, but it will be easier if you use maven to handle all the dependencies for you

Answer (score 0):

- If your project is using Maven, then use the [latest](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.12.4) dependency from Maven central repository
- If you are using Gradle then use:

```
  dependencies {
      compile 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.0.3'
  }
```

- Finally, [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/driver/getting-started/quick-start/) is a quick start guide and more to get your started with using the actual driver.